# About Beta function $B(\alpha,r\alpha +1)‎\rightarrow‎ 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, special-functions, gamma-function

I want to show that 
$$B(\alpha,r\alpha +1)‎\rightarrow‎ 0$$ when $r‎\rightarrow‎ \infty$ and 
$0< \alpha <1$.

with thanks

Answer (score 1):

From
$$
\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma (x)\Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x+y)}
$$ you get
$$
\mathrm{B}(\alpha,r\alpha +1)=\frac{\Gamma (\alpha)\Gamma (r\alpha+1)}{\Gamma ((r+1)\alpha+1)}
$$ then use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), as $z \to \infty$,
$$
\Gamma(z) = \sqrt{2\pi} z^{z - 1/2} e^{-z} (1 + O(1/z))
$$ to get, as $\alpha \to \infty$,

> $$
> \mathrm{B}(\alpha,r\alpha +1)\sim\frac{\Gamma (\alpha)}{\alpha^\alpha}\frac1{r^\alpha},\quad \quad 0<\alpha<1.
> $$

The announced result follows.